# Windows Forms: User controls and events

Tags: .net, winforms, user-controls

I have a **Windows Forms** user control which consists of several controls. Among others there is also gridview control. Now I want to use the user control in a form. How can I check for example if a grid row is clicked? I want to get the data of the selected row.
In other words, how can I detect events of the controls, which are embedded in the user control?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to expose the events from your parent control by adding additional events:

```
public event EventHandler GridViewClicked;
```

And you call it on your child control using the following:

```
private void ChildControlGrid_RowClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (GridViewClicked != null)
    {
        GridViewClicked(sender, e);
    }
}
```

You then implement this the same way you would any event on your form:

```
yourControl.GridViewClicked += new EventHandler(ChildGridRowClicked);

private void ChildGridRowClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Child row clicked
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a new event on your user control and use it to expose the events of the gridview.